# Maximize frame and deactivate resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize

I want a frame that is maximized and after that I want to block resizing. For that I wrote the following Code:

```
public PaintingWindow() {
    initComponents();
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setResizable(false);
}
```

The problem: The window isn't maximized any more if I add the setResizeable(false). Without it it is working.

How can I evade it?
Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Consider having a look at full screen exclusive mode

Comment: It works here (Windows 10, Java 8), with the call to `setResizable(..)` either before or after `setExtendedState(..)`. But there, try it the other way around. `setReiszable(..)` will change the 'chrome' of the window (the wrapping around the outside) & that might confuse the OS into thinking it should come back from full-screen. More generally: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with JFrame i was able to solve it by `frame.setVisible(true);` before `frame.setResizable(false);`

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setSize(screenSize);
frame.setVisible(true); 
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: just to amend, the Javadoc of setExtendedState says:"If the frame is not visible on the screen, the events may or may not be generated. ... Later, when the setVisible(true) method is invoked, the frame will attempt to apply this state." - but if resizable is false before setVisible, it will fail to apply the state.